# React Router v4 and nested routes: index navlink always remain active

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Currently i have this routing structure:

//Main.js:

```
 <Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={AuthApp}/>
        <Route path='/app' component={ContentApp}/>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

I need some inner navigation inside of my ContentApp:

```
//ContentApp:
<Route exact path={`${match.url}/`} component={Content}/>
<Route exact path={`${match.url}/something`} component={Something}/>
<Route exact path={`${match.url}/else`} component={Else}/>
<Route exact path={`${match.url}/blahblah`} component={BlahBlah}/>
```

And some navigation ofc:

```
//Header.js
<NavLink exact to='/app' >Dashboard</NavLink>
<NavLink to='/app/something' >Something</NavLink>
<NavLink to='/app/else' >Else</NavLink>
<NavLink to='/app/blahblah' >BlahBlah</NavLink>
```

So the thing is: its working just fine, however the first link always remains active. Can anyone suggest how can i solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: sorry what do you mean `the first link` which link?

Comment: I believe they mean that /app always shows as active, even if, say, /app/else is active (or any of the other links beneath /app). I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

In React Router V6 Use `end= {true}`, Just like the example in Below,

```
<NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) =>
                isActive ? "active nav-link" : "nav-link"
              }
              to="/admin/new"
            >
              Add New
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <NavLink
              className={({ isActive }) =>
                isActive ? "active nav-link" : "nav-link"
              }
              to="/admin"
              end={true}
            >
              Manage
            </NavLink>
```

In This Example, I use Two routes `/admin` and `/admin/new` to detect `/admin/new` path I added `end= {true}`.

Answer (score 3):

Just modify your `NavLink` to:

```
//Header.js
<NavLink exact to='/app' >Dashboard</NavLink>
<NavLink exact to='/app/something' >Something</NavLink>
<NavLink exact to='/app/else' >Else</NavLink>
<NavLink exact to='/app/blahblah' >BlahBlah</NavLink>
```